# Angular - Importing module causes lambda error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing a library and I got everything working apart from integrating the library with an actual app. I get a lambda error but I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Here is the error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol NgModule in //ng/lib-ng/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol Components in //ng/lib-ng/dist/modules/components.module.d.ts, resolving symbol Components in //ng/lib-ng/dist/modules/components.module.d.ts

And here's the module that throws it:

**providers.ts**

```
export const COMPONENTS_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
  BreadcrumbsUtils,
  ModalApi,
  NotificationsApi,
  SiteHeaderApi
];
```

**components.module.ts**

```
import {COMPONENTS_PROVIDERS} from '../components/providers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BreadcrumbsModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    CheckboxesModule,
    DataListModule,
    DropdownModule,
    DropdownSelectModule,
    FileUploaderModule,
    ModalModule,
    NotificationsModule,
    SearchInputModule,
    SelectModule,
    SelectMultipleModule,
    SiteFooterModule,
    SiteHeaderModule,
    SwitchModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BreadcrumbsModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    CheckboxesModule,
    DataListModule,
    DropdownModule,
    DropdownSelectModule,
    FileUploaderModule,
    ModalModule,
    NotificationsModule,
    SearchInputModule,
    SelectModule,
    SelectMultipleModule,
    SiteFooterModule,
    SiteHeaderModule,
    SwitchModule
  ]
})

export class Components {

  public static forRoot() {

    return {
      ngModule: Components,
      providers: COMPONENTS_PROVIDERS
    };
  }
}
```

The `AppModule` that is used to test the lib:

```
import {Components} from '../../lib-ng';

@NgModule({
  imports: [

    // Throws error
    Components.forRoot()

    // Importing it without calling forRoot throws the same error
    Components
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What does your `COMPONENTS_PROVIDERS` array look like?

Comment: @Brad Updated question with services & the modules themselves.

Comment: What does your `Components` look like?

Comment: @Aravind It's right there in the question.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz what's wrong with that question?

Comment: @Aravind What? I updated the question with the original so you can see exactly what it looks like.

Comment: Are you using AOT compilation or angular Cli to build the app?Can you post your package.json in the question.

Comment: @Niladri The library uses AOT when compiling it. But the app doesn't when I use `ng serve` to test it.

Comment: so you are getting the error only when you build your library with AOT right? Can you check whether you have the below `peerDependencies` in your package.json 
`peerDependencies: {
  "@angular/common": "^2.4.10",
  ...
}`
This looks like AOT issue to me . Check this link for more help 
[link]https://blog.angularindepth.com/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5

Comment: @Niladri the library builds just fine. But when the demo app imports it that's when it breaks. It breaks regardless of importing the compiled `dist` version or the original version that's pure `ts`. I do not have that. My lib `package.json` has peer deps of `^4.0.0`.

Comment: Have you tried moving `providers` into the `@NgModule` decorator definition?  The `forRoot()` function may not be necessary.

Comment: @Brad I get the same error even when removing everything from providers, imports, exports and the forRoot. So I don't know what could be the issue...